# Python calculate the remaining time of a forloop?

Tags: python, tqdm

I have a Python script that should always put two words together with a forloop from a word list and then write them into a password list.
That works perfectly too. But since the whole thing can take a few minutes, I would like to calculate the remaining time. I found some solutions on the internet, but didn't know how to apply them properly to my script.

My script:

```
from itertools import permutations

print("Please enter a filename: \n")
my_file = open(input(str()), "r")
content = my_file.readlines()
converted_content = []

for element in content:
    converted_content.append(element.strip())

print("Successfully removed line breaks from list!")

with open("generated_passwords.txt", "w") as i:
    for perm in permutations(converted_content, 2):
        ''.join(list(perm))
        i.write("%s\n" % "".join(list(perm)))


print("\nGenerated password-list!")
```

I tried to install tqdm in my forloop, but this led to the following output.

```
import tqdm
import time

with open("generated_passwords.txt", "w") as i:
    for perm in permutations(converted_content, 2):
        ''.join(list(perm))
        i.write("%s\n" % "".join(list(perm)))

        for p in tqdm.tqdm(perm):
            time.sleep(0.01)
```

Output:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 98.88it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 98.93it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 98.86it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 99.03it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 98.81it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 98.71it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:00<00:00, 98.82it/s]
etc.
```

**But I only want one bar for the entire forloop. Can this work at all and if so, how?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not really familiar with `tqdm`, however on their [github page](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) it is stated:

> Instantly make your loops show a smart progress meter - just wrap any iterable with tqdm(iterable), and you're done!

So in your case, the solution is to wrap `permutations(converted_content, 2)` in `tqdm()` like so: `tqdm(permutations(converted_content, 2))`

Comment: Thank's for your answer. But it looks like the loop doesn't stop anymore, I get this output all the time: 210it [00:02, 84.69it/s]
210it [00:02, 89.68it/s]
210it [00:02, 92.89it/s] etc.

Comment: I can't really help you since I don't have access to the file that you are using. I reproduced your code and for me, it is working perfectly fine.